# How to run every 10 seconds in GCP Cloud Scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron

What would be a correct syntax for the Cloud Scheduler Frequency field to run it every 10 seconds?

I've been using https://crontab.guru/ but it seems to be missing the `seconds` and starts with minutes, hours and etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google Cloud Scheduler does not support seconds. The smallest scheduling interval is one minute.

Answer (score 7):

As John said, it's not possible. As alternative, you can call a function with a Cloud Scheduler that create an [HTTP task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks) in a Task Queue.

In this function, set the scheduledTime every 10s for XX tasks and the final HTTP request that you want to perform. Be careful to the timeout and the retry policy and apply them according to your use case